# python's ggplot does not use year number as label on axis

Tags: python, pandas, python-ggplot

In the following MWE, my `year` variable is shown on the x-axis as 0 to 6 instead of the actual year number. Why is this?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import wb
from ggplot import *

dat = wb.download(
    indicator=['BX.KLT.DINV.CD.WD', 'BX.KLT.DINV.WD.GD.ZS'],
    country='CN', start=2005, end=2011)
dat.reset_index(inplace=True)

print ggplot(aes(x='year', y='BX.KLT.DINV.CD.WD'),
       data=dat) + \
    geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is convert the `year` column from an `object` `dtype` to `datetime64`:

```
dat['year'] = pd.to_datetime(dat['year'])
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly -- could you add a few words explaining why python ggplot chooses to format the x axis so weirdly without converting? I've literally never seen any graphics system that try to display 2006 as 1 + 2.005e3

Comment: Not really sure, but the data in the `year` column was in `unicode` type, which means ggplot has to parse it to some number-like `type` before actually plotting. Most likely that parser has some strange behavior resulting in 1 + 2.005e3. I do agree with you it is a strange behavior.

Comment: By the way, if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark (not only upvote). Thanks.